# Import External Provider users into asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, openid-connect

I have a web-app that combines asp.net identity with an external provider (azuread).
The login and authentication works so that's already great.

The issue is that we can only assign roles after a user does the first authentication.

Is there any way I can import the azure ad users into the identity system so that we can assign the security roles without having the users login first?

I was lookig into the login process for external providers but could not find the part that creates the info in the database.